# Медленная загрузка архивов на сервер

Tags: python-3.x, django, nginx, uwsgi

Имеется сайт (python3/django, uwsgi, nginx) и есть простая форма(POST)  с загрузкой файла. Столкнулся с проблемой медленной загрузки файлов (архивов) >30Мб.

Замерял скорость:

- Архив 5мб - 2-3 сек;
- Архив 40Мб - 60 сек;

Не понимаю почему такое большое расхождение между скоростью, судя по скорости загрузки архива в 5Мб, то архив в 40Мб должен загружаться за 12-15сек почему такая проблема?

В django/settings поставил выгрузку файлов в оперативку(100Мб):

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 104857600
```

Падает именно скорость загрузки файла, отслеживаю загрузку с помощью xhr:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'/ajax/upload/',
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
    data:formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr, opts){},
    xhr: function(){
        let xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
            if(e.lengthComputable){
                let progress = Math.ceil(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
                progress_bar
                    .css('width', progress + '%')
                    .attr('aria-valuenow', progress)
                    .text('Заливка ' + progress + '%');
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    success:function(data) {
    .....
    }
});
```

Comment: А интернет какой? Может, не в Джанго дело?

Comment: попробуйте проверить тоже самое без django и сравните. врятли тут виновата django

Comment: @Александр Инет 1 Гигабит, оперативки 256Гб, так-что вряд-ли проблема в этом. Скорее всего где-то в Django или Nginx.

Comment: слишком много неизвестных в вашем вопросе, например архив этот сервер может автоматически распаковывать... да куча вариантов.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev тут имеется ввиду именно загрузка на сервер, не считая обработок архива. Почему-то скорость загрузки у больших архив падает.

Comment: Ну пусть так, и какая работа по диагностике была проделана? Трассировка? Проверка скорости работы интернета на приемку и отдачу с сервера и клиента?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev напрямую через sftp 40Мб архив грузится за 12-15сек. Правил вопрос, написал как я отслеживаю загрузку.